# Change background color on emojicon library

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme

I want to use an emoji library, and I found [rockerhieu's emojicon library](https://github.com/rockerhieu/emojicon) which seems to work great, but I want to change the background of the keyboard to white instead of black, how could I achieve that?

I'm using the `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try to:**

Replace keyboard_background_holo.9.png (Black) image to below white 9.patch image in your library drawable folder.
[image]

**OR**

Replace your library layout/emojicons.xml file code with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/emojis_tab"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        >

        <ImageButton
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:id="@+id/emojis_tab_0_recents"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_emoji_recent_light" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1px"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/horizontal_vertical" />

        <ImageButton
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:id="@+id/emojis_tab_1_people"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_emoji_people_light" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1px"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/horizontal_vertical" />

        <ImageButton
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:id="@+id/emojis_tab_2_nature"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_emoji_nature_light" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1px"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/horizontal_vertical" />

        <ImageButton
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:id="@+id/emojis_tab_3_objects"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_emoji_objects_light" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1px"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/horizontal_vertical" />

        <ImageButton
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:id="@+id/emojis_tab_4_cars"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_emoji_places_light" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1px"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/horizontal_vertical" />

        <ImageButton
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:id="@+id/emojis_tab_5_punctuation"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_emoji_symbols_light" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1px"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/horizontal_vertical" />

        <ImageButton
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/emojis_backspace"
            android:src="@drawable/sym_keyboard_delete_holo_dark" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_below="@id/emojis_tab"
        android:id="@+id/emojis_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        android:layout_below="@id/emojis_tab"
        android:background="@color/horizontal_divider" />
</RelativeLayout>
```